# What are the units for the time remaining value in GitHub's rate limiting message?

Tags: github-api

According to [GitHub's API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting), when you go over the rate limit, you get a response that looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2013 14:50:41 GMT
Status: 403 Forbidden
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1377013266

{
    "message": "API rate limit exceeded for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"
}
```

What are the units on the `X-RateLimit-Reset` value? In other words, how can I tell from the error message how long in seconds or minutes I need to wait before I can send another request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Unix timestamp, see [this note from the GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-07-02-rate-limit-reset/).

With the timestamp from that example the reset time would have been 20 Aug 2013 at 15:41:06.

According to a [Wikipedia article the GitHub docs link to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), a Unix timestamp is:

> defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds.

Comment: Thanks! I added some more information from the docs you linked to. Is that all right?

Comment: Perfect! And now i've added the conversion :)